# Unexpected addition operator with my class

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I apologize if the question is Naive.

I am trying to overload the addition operator for fractions. My intent was to add fractions but for some reason it is adding the integers. Can some one explain why is it performing the integer addition. Code is below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;



class Fraction{
  long numerator;
  long denominator;
  long gcd(long num1, long num2);
  long lcm(long num1, long num2);
public:
  void convert_int_to_fraction(int num); 
  void reduce();
  Fraction(int num);
  Fraction(){
    numerator = 0;
    denominator = 0;
  }
  Fraction(long num, long den);
  Fraction operator+(Fraction fraction);
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Fraction& fracNumber);

};

void Fraction::convert_int_to_fraction(int num){
    denominator = 1;
    numerator = long(num);
    reduce();
}

Fraction::Fraction(int num){
    convert_int_to_fraction(num);
}

long Fraction::gcd(long num1, long num2){
    if(num1 == 0)
        return num2;
    else
        return (gcd(num2 % num1, num1));
}

//Math function to calculate LCM
long Fraction::lcm(long num1,  long num2){
    long great_Divisor = gcd(num1, num2);
    return ((num1/great_Divisor) * num2);
}

//Reduce fraction to its minimal
void Fraction::reduce(){
    if(denominator!=0){
        long great_Divisor = gcd(numerator, denominator);
        numerator /= great_Divisor;
        denominator /= great_Divisor;
        if(denominator < 0 && numerator > 0){
            denominator = -denominator;
            numerator = -numerator;
        }
    }
}

Fraction::Fraction(long num, long den):numerator(num), denominator(den){
    reduce();
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Fraction& fracNumber){
    os << fracNumber.numerator << "/" << fracNumber.denominator ;
    return os;
}

Fraction Fraction::operator+(Fraction fraction){
    Fraction result;
    long least_Multiple = lcm(denominator, fraction.denominator);
    result.denominator = (least_Multiple);
    long result_Numerator = ((numerator * (least_Multiple/denominator)) + 
                                (fraction.numerator * (least_Multiple/fraction.denominator)));
    result.numerator = (result_Numerator);
    result.reduce();
    return result;
}

int main(){
  Fraction frac1(2,4);
  cout << frac1 + 2  << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The output is 5/2 So I tried to do it the other way round

```
  cout << 2 + frac1   << endl;
```

This is giving me error. So now I tried to fix this by implementing these two functions.

```
Fraction::operator int(){
    return convert_fraction_to_int();
}
int Fraction::convert_fraction_to_int(){
    return ((int)(numerator/denominator));
}
```

Now even the first operation cout doesnt work. But the best thing is everything works fine when I typecast the variables. Can anyone explain why it is working in the first case, why not in the second case and why broken in the third case.

Comment: You should have implemented an overload of `+` that takes an `int` as a first argument, and a const reference to `Fraction` as the second argument.  Speaking of that, you should really pass `Fraction` as const references to your functions, not by value.

Comment: @RSahu so there is. Missed that.

Comment: There's no need to use so many parentheses, saying `return (foo);` is completely unnecessary, as is `foo = (bar);`

Comment: My opinion -- I would get rid of the `Fraction(int)` constructor.  It serves no purpose except for confusion.  If a user wants a whole number, they should be smart enough to use `Fraction(2,1)` to denote `2`, for example.

Comment: Further to Paul's first comment, your `operator+` doesn't modify `*this` so why is it a non-const member function? It should be a non-member function taking two arguments.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie So you mean to say I have to overload + operator again so it performs the int + frac addition ? Thanks.

Comment: You want to have an `int` as the first argument, and the `Fraction` as the second argument.   The functions that take a `Fraction` first will not match `2 + Fraction`.

Comment: I understand, also can you explain why the working function is broken after adding operator int() and convert_fraction_to_int() functions. Because fraction + 2 is working fine in the first case but is broken after adding the two functions.

Comment: @Random -- It was outlined in the answer and comment by RSahu, but you should not go overboard with these conversion operators.  The reason is that many times, you have no idea what functions are really being called behind the scenes when conversion operators are being used.  The other reason as stated already is that there is a good chance the compiler won't be able to choose a function to call due to ambiguity.  To avoid all of this, reduce, if not eliminate conversion operators, and instead have named functions to return `int`, such as `get_int()`.

Comment: @Random Note it isn't just beginners at C++ that have trouble being sure what functions are really called, professional C++ programmers when asked what functions will be called in the presence of conversion operators may also not know for sure.  It is only when you start debugging do you see the gauntlet that is run when you have conversion ops in the mix (which can lead to *slower* code due to all the conversion you never knew were going on).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you, I appreciate your help and advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> .My intent was to add fractions but for some reason it is adding the integers. Can some one explain why is it performing the integer addition.

There is a converting constructor from `int` to `Fraction`.

`frac1 + 2` is being converted to `frac1 + Fraction(2)` by the compiler.

**Update**

If you want the compiler to be able support both `frac1 + 2` and `2 + frac1`, you can make the `operator+` function a non-member function.

```
friend Fraction operator+(Fraction const& lhs, Fraction const& rhs);
```

and implement it as:

```
Fraction operator+(Fraction const& lhs, Fraction const& rhs)
{
   Fraction result;

   // Needed to make lcm and gcd static member functions since
   // they work independent of the member variables.

   long least_Multiple = Fraction::lcm(lhs.denominator, rhs.denominator);
   result.denominator = (least_Multiple);
   long result_Numerator = ((lhs.numerator * (least_Multiple/lhs.denominator)) + 
                            (rhs.numerator * (least_Multiple/rhs.denominator)));
   result.numerator = (result_Numerator);
   result.reduce();
   return result;
}
```

Now, you can use

```
Fraction frac1(2,4);
Fraction frac2(3,7);
cout << frac1 + 2  << endl;
cout << 3 + frac1  << endl;
cout << frac1 + frac2 << endl;
```

Comment: Correct me of I am wrong, the reason why it is not adding 2 + frac is that compiler is not converting frac into Integer(Fraction) since it is not defined.

Comment: Also why is it failing after adding operator int() and convert_fraction_to_int() functions. Thank you

Comment: @Random, no, that is not the reason. In order for `2 + frac` to work, `2` has to be converted to `Fraction(2)`. There are some language rules why the compiler is not able to do that.

Comment: @Random, adding `convert_fraction_to_int()` should have no bearing on the `operator+` function. Adding `operator int()` will be a problem though. With the presence of `operator int()`, the expression `frac + 2` can be converted to `frac + Fraction(2)` or `frac.operator int() + 2`. Since both of require a conversion and neither has higher precedence, the compiler cannot choose which one to use.

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much. Its been clear to me. I appreciate your help :D.